# Close div when another is opened and clicked outside with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried different method to solved this issue.
I want to make it when when clicked outside or another button to close the dropdown menu.

With below code i just can make it clicked outside div close the dropdown menu,
but when i clicked another menu button it come out two dropdown menu.

I want to use class to make the dropdown button globally.

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $triggerWrapper = $(".tm-dropdown-button");
  var $triggerMenu = $(".tm-dropdown-content");

  if (($triggerWrapper !== e.target && !$triggerWrapper.has(e.target).length)) {
    if (($triggerMenu !== e.target && !$triggerMenu.has(e.target).length)) {
      $('.tm-dropdown').removeClass('opened');
    }
  }
  console.log($(e.target).length);
});

$(".tm-dropdown-button").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.parent().hasClass('opened')) {
    $this.parent().removeClass('opened');
  } else {
    $this.parent().addClass('opened');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tm-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.tm-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tm-dropdown-content li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tm-dropdown.opening .tm-dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  visibility: visible;
}
.tm-dropdown.opened .tm-dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tm-dropdown.p-start .tm-dropdown-content {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}
.tm-dropdown.p-end .tm-dropdown-content {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
</style>
<div class="tm-dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="tm-button tm-button-primary-l6 tm-button-ghost text-grey-medium tm-dropdown-button" aria-describedby="tooltip">
            <span>EN</span>
        </button>
  <ul class="tm-dropdown-content" role="tooltip">
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Bahasa Melayu</li>
    <li>中文简体</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tm-dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="tm-button tm-button-primary-l6 tm-button-ghost text-grey-medium tm-dropdown-button" aria-describedby="tooltip">
            <span>EN</span>
        </button>
  <ul class="tm-dropdown-content" role="tooltip">
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Bahasa Melayu</li>
    <li>中文简体</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code.
Here in this code on body click we can just close all opened dropdowns.

In the button click, we first stop the event propagation so that the event will not bubble up. This way we can add listener for the current clicked event only. In the listener we first get hold of current element and close all other opened dropdown. Then we toggle the current element.

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  // On body click close all opened dropdowns
  if ($(e.target).closest('.tm-dropdown').length === 0) {
    $('.tm-dropdown').removeClass('opened'); 
  }
});

$(".tm-dropdown-button").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Stop propagation so event will not bubble to elements other than this in the tree above
  var $this = $(this);
  var parent = $this.parent();
  
  // Close all other opened dropdowns except this
  $('.tm-dropdown').not(parent).removeClass('opened');

    // This will open/close the clicked dropdown
  if (parent.hasClass('opened')) {
    parent.removeClass('opened');
  } else {
    parent.addClass('opened');
  }
});
```

```css
.tm-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.tm-dropdown.opened .tm-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="tm-dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="tm-button tm-button-primary-l6 tm-button-ghost text-grey-medium tm-dropdown-button" aria-describedby="tooltip">
            <span>EN</span>
        </button>
  <ul class="tm-dropdown-content" role="tooltip">
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Bahasa Melayu</li>
    <li>中文简体</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tm-dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="tm-button tm-button-primary-l6 tm-button-ghost text-grey-medium tm-dropdown-button" aria-describedby="tooltip">
            <span>EN</span>
        </button>
  <ul class="tm-dropdown-content" role="tooltip">
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Bahasa Melayu</li>
    <li>中文简体</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work, the menu items can't click, it will close the menu before the menu items is click.

Comment: Which menu items you are talking about?

Comment: .tm-dropdown-content is not clickedable if  on start $('.tm-dropdown').removeClass('opened');

Comment: @Kelvin I thought these are just text and not clickable links as you had li elements. Answer Updated